# how to specify range if we are taking an array in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am learning python and i wanted to iterate only specified number of time but using an array variable.
I searched over the net that we can use range function for it.

But I'm not able to iterate using range()

here is my simplified code:-

```
array=[1,2,3,4,5]

for record in array:
    print(record)
```

I wanted to print only first 3 indexes.
Here i just have taken numbers in array for reference actually i'm pilling content from an text file and storing it in array and printing it line by line. And then do further sorting

Here is the code i'm trying :-

```
array=[1,2,3,4,5]

for record in range(0,2,array):
    print(record)
```

Error I'm getting:-
List object cannot be interpreted as integer

Comment: first three is: `for record in array[:3]:`

Comment: @Stephen Rauch it's working.........thnx mate for helping .

Comment: Also the error you received is because the third position in range is responsible for the length of steps it will take. For example by default it is 1 so it will increment one at a time. But you have given an array which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There's various routes that you can take. Assuming you want to print the first 3 elements of your array, here's two:

```
array=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

1) Slice the array

```
# start at index 0 and go until index 2
for record in array[0:3]: 
    print(record)
```

2) Use a variable to iterate over the array

```
# range(3) = [0, 1, 2]
for i in range(3): 
    print(array[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code part-

`array=[1,2,3,4,5]`

`for record in range(0,2,array):
    print(record)`

The range function takes 3 parameters. First one is starting index,second one is ending index and the third one is the gap in which you want the numbers to be. So,going by an example-

for i in range(0,5,2):
    print(i)

This code will print 0,2,4 as answer. The range function will start from 0 and will return every 2nd number till 4(not 5,because 5 is excluded).

**Your code gives an error because you have mentioned an array as your 3rd parameter but it is expecting an integer**

`for record in range(0,2,len(array)):
    print(record)`

You could try this,but it will only return 0 because essentially this for loop simplifies to-

`for record in range(0,2,5)`

So after returning the starting number it will try to get the next 5th number which you dont have(as 2nd parameter is 2). Hope this clarifies.